# Highcharts add data series dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, highcharts

I know this question has probably already been asked, but I just couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.

The problem is: I use a PHP script to generate a JSON string, this string is used as input for a ng-repeat which sends it through a directive, which in turn uses it to create a series of Highchart charts. I have manipulated the data so that it would only be a matter of `chart.addNewSeries(name, data)` but that isn't possible, so I have been looking for a solution to this but couldn't find anything.

Here is the code I have so far:

The PHP that provides the JSON

```
$sql = "SELECT info.position, info.date, info.keyword, url.url
    FROM Concurrentie_position AS info
    INNER JOIN Concurrentie_sitename AS url ON info.record_id = url.id
    ORDER BY info.date";

$urlData = array();
$dates = array();
global $conn;

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $matchFound = false;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($urlData); $i++) {
        if($urlData[$i]["keyword"] == $row["keyword"]){
            addDates($row["date"]);
            $urlData[$i]["urlpos"][$row["url"]][] = $row["position"];
            $matchFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!$matchFound) {
        $urlData[] = array(
            "keyword" => $row["keyword"],
            "urlpos" => array(
                $row["url"] => array($row["position"])
            )
        );
    }
}
addDatesToArr();

function addDatesToArr(){
    global $urlData, $dates;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($urlData); $i++){
        $urlData[$i]["date"] = $dates;
    }
}
echo json_encode($urlData);
```

This is the controller the data end up into:

```
var dataList = filterSites();


var chart = new Highcharts.chart('container'+$scope.index, {
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {

        text: 'Aantal downloads'
    },
    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        categories: $scope.date
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: { text:'Donwloads' },
        floor: 0,
        ceiling: 10
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name} <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b>'
    }
});
for(var i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++){
    addSeriesToChart(dataList[i].url, dataList[i].positions);
}

function addSeriesToChart(url, position){
    series = {
        name: url,
        data: position
    };
    chart.addSeries(series, true);
}

function filterSites(){
    var urlList = [];
    var urlPosList = [];
    for(var key in $scope.urlpos) urlList.push(key);
    for(var i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++){
        if(urlList[i].indexOf("leerzelfbeleggen.com") > -1 || urlList[i].indexOf("hoebeleggen.be") > -1 || urlList[i].indexOf("onlinebeleggen.info") > -1 || urlList[i].indexOf("allesoverbeleggen.com") > -1 || urlList[i].indexOf("beginbeleggen.nl") > -1){
            var dataObject = {
                url: urlList[i],
                positions: $scope.urlpos[urlList[i]]
            }
            urlPosList.push(dataObject);
        }
    }
    return urlPosList;
}
```

It creates some `Series` objects but it kinda seems like it adds series to already existing series. Please help me figure out how to add new series on the fly.

Comment: What do you mean by "it adds series to already existing series" ? As in, it adds data to the series that are already there? Or it adds more series instead of replacing the existing ones?  the addSeries() function is meant to do just that - add new series. It won't replace. Can you clarify your expected result, and what's not working?

Comment: @jlbriggs I work with Rik on the issue. When it adds the series you will get an Highchart object with loads of items, on of which is series. You would expect that the series object will be filled with an array containing object with the name and data, but instead there is another object which looks like the whole Highchard object again, see link for example: http://i.imgur.com/xqWGusf.png. The expected result is that it will fill the series with an array containing the name,data objects needed to draw the chart so: [{name: "Test", data:[1,5,2,6,3,6]},{name:"test2", data:[4,2,6,7,2,1]}] etc.

Comment: The Highcharts object that gets created is a large complex object that allows you to access the full chart options from various points. Looking at that image, I can't say whether it is right or wrong. Is the chart rendered correctly on the page?

Comment: The chart object seems to be OK, it is only missing the lines that is representing the data, which is logical, because we don't give the chart any data when we initialize it.